# Object Oriented C++ library for ssh and scp

Tags: c++, ssh, scp

Is there any Object Oriented C++ library for ssh and scp. BSD license would be preferred.

I could find libssh and libssh2. But these are all procedural.

Answer (score 5):

With libssh version 0.5 the library comes with a nice C++ wrapper. It's in the include directory and called libsshpp.h

I hope this will suite your needs. Else open a feature request.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at NetSieben SSH Library - an open source ssh client library in C++:

http://freshmeat.net/projects/net7ssh/

Answer (score 1):

I use cryptlib for this. It is free for Opensource and Freeware applications and easy to use.
http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/cryptlib/

/mspoerr