# How to programmatically create ssh tunnel in C/C++ cross-platform?

Tags: c, windows, linux, ios, ssh

I need to connect via TCP to a port that's behind a firewall, accessible through an SSH tunnel.  I can achieve connection by opening a tunnel and hittting that port, but I want to build this tunneling in to my application.

Additionally, I want to be able to provide automatic login by use of having authorized keys on the server

This must work on the following platforms (in order of importance)

- iOS (trickiest because I can't fork an ssh tunnel like I can on other platforms)
- OS X
- Linux
- Windows

What's the easy way to do this?  I don't want to spend a great deal of effort obviously since this isn't the meat of my application.  But I'll reuse it so I may care enough to "do things right"

Comment: Have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992374/object-oriented-c-library-for-ssh-and-scp ? This looks pretty close to an exact duplicate...

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: Well, Nektarios is asking for an SSH tunnel, whereas the other one is just asking for an SSH library. :)

Comment: [Libssh](http://libssh.org) is a very good client implementation for SSH protocol. I have written [a blog](http://www.webyog.com/blog/2012/09/12/how-to-integrating-ssh-tunneling-inside-your-application) on this. There is also a sample application demonstrating the same. We use the same technique in [MONyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/downloads.php#monyog) (MySQL monitor).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**But libssh2 is BSD-licensed and appears to have the functionality needed**

Looks like: **libssh2_channel_direct_tcpip_ex** will be the call

**Note** that the LGPL'd libssh is a problem because on iOS apps you MUST statically link and CANNOT dynamically link to libraries.  Therefore, using an LGPL'd library means my source becomes open source.

Comment: If you look at the (probably biased) comparison (http://www.libssh2.org/libssh2-vs-libssh.html), libssh2 might be a better choice.

Comment: I also agree that libssh2 even for non-blocking is best.

Comment: The LGPL problem is correct. However the libssh2 vs libssh page is outdated and so incorrect. libssh has a lot more features than libssh2 like ECDSA, ECDH kex, GSSAPI etc. http://www.libssh.org/features/

Answer (score -3):

Does the LGPL differentiate between linking dynamically and statically? I don't think so.

The library code (i.e. embedding your own SSH implementation) looks most versatile to me. Except the fact that you might inherit security problems.

On MacOSX/Linux/Unix, you can simply invoke 'ssh' and assume it exists (or make it as a precondition). On Windows, you would rely on putty and friends. I don't think that's a good idea.

Comment: The LPGL *does* differentiate between linking dynamically and statically.

Comment: @Jörgen - Oh, I see, I wasn't aware of that at all and could have sworn the opposite - I'm not a GPL/LGPL license specialist at all. So, LGPL'ed libraries are usually not a problem (on a desktop/server) because most programs are used dynamically.

Comment: Well, the LGPL doesn't say it out loud, but if you put pieces together, it hints at it. Also, here are some words from Moglen (FSF's legal top dog): http://www.spinics.net/lists/xf/msg02311.html (scroll down a little, or search for "Code statically linked to other"). He says "Code statically linked to other code is a derivative work of the code with which it is linked, as far as we are concerned.". This gives me the chills, because the LGPL requires you to disclose derivative works.

Comment: The LGPL link referenced above is horrible period seeing as how 2 top experts from the FSF say almost completely different things. I have in the past released under GPL and never again want anything to do with it if at all possible.  I wonder how many iPhone/iPad apps are in violation of these licenses and have no idea (you MUST statically link on iOS devices to be accepted to app store)